# Detect write to string

Tags: c, string, memory

Is there a way for me to detect/initiate-creash-on a write into a string without using mprotect (which I can't use)?

Currently I can detect the write only in the following read, but that's too late (the following read can come from a completely different lib).

Note: Using gdb with watchpoints failed due to optimizer moving the string around in the process memory.

Edit: The variable in question is a class member (char*) that contains some metadata as a prefix to a string. The string is the part that needs to be immutable, and the prefix must be writable. I've got a few millions of these objects in a class-static hash, and they are accessed from just about anywhere in our code.

Comment: How about using gdb watchpoints on an unoptimized code?

Comment: Because I can't reproduce the error on another machine and to replace all the libs\execs to unoptimized will require re-install of the OS (it's very low-level code)

Comment: Isn't `watch myString` independent of where the optimizer has placed your string `myString`? Isn't it the headache of the debugger to figure out where in memory is `myString`?

Comment: It is, but I'm watching specific memory addresses. The string itself is not the problem, but a sub-section in it. If I watch a memory address "watch" can't account for optimizing.

Comment: @Neowizard Can you post some code so that we can deduce more about the variable you are trying to watch? Cos, if its a global variable, then you can check your `.map` file for the exact address of the variable and then use it in GDB?

Comment: @PavanManjunath, I can't add source, but I've added a bit of info about my situation in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to wrap all the code that writes to memory in preprocessor macros which check the address that you're using but since most people love to use bare bones pointers (instead of library calls that encapsulate things), it will probably be a lot of effort.

The only other option is `mprotect(2)` or GDB which all use special parts of the CPU to watch the address bus for accesses to the memory in question.

Since you can't use that either, the last option is to print the code on paper and sit down in a quiet corner for a couple of days to read it. This will usually work but most people shun the effort (and because it doesn't look like "real" work ;-).

Comment: I'd love to be able to have a look at all the relevant code, but it's well over several millions of potential lines of code. Currently I'm trying to single out the guilty libraries to narrow down the search.

Comment: If it's always the same string that gets garbled, then the offending code must somehow get its address. This means it can't be completely unrelated to the code that creates/uses the string.

Comment: True, it's the same process, but it's a gigantic process. Anyways, I did manage to narrow it down to the relevant process flow, and from there it was just a matter of reading the code with a with great attention...too me it looked like "real" (and eventually very effective) work :).

Comment: Code reviews are the most cost effective way to find and fix bugs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review). My quip was against the common misconception that "reading" isn't "work" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a command in gdb similar to "trace" in dbx, but in dbx I remember using a command called "trace" that can be used to track individual variables in the code and it intimates you when the variable value gets changed during the course of execution.

Comment: `trace` doesn't do what you say here. According to DBX docs-`trace-Have tracing information printed when the program is executed`. In fact, `stop <variable>` does that! Referring to DBX docs-`stop-             Stop execution when the given line is reached,procedure or function entered, variable changed,module loaded or unloaded, or condition true`

And `watch` is the nearest equivalent of `stop` in GDB

Comment: Yes, tracing information means it prints as and when the value in a particular variable changes when the program is in execution. Stop can be used if you want the program to stop as soon as the value in the variable changes. trace continues execution printing every time the variable value changes.